# Prevent elements to be placed on new rows when created but allowing x scroll on elements container

Tags: css

I'm developing an app where you can create many columns with text boxes. Those columns are created by the user and are wrapped in a "column container" thingy.

The thing is when creating a new one without space enough on the container to be shown it's placed on a new row. I would like to achieve the creation of multiple of those columns with an X-overlfow so I could scroll horizontally instead of getting infinite new rows.

I've tried this on wrapper CSS:

`overflow-x: scroll;`

And this is the CSS of each column:

```
  height: calc(100% - 10%); 
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 10%);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 10%);
  float: left;
  overflow:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
```

Comment: Any reason you're note using flex ? It sounds like a perfect job for a flex parent.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Because I don't want the columns to be resized to fit. I want to keep the same sizing, I just wan't to add a scroll-x to the wrapper when a child (or more) doesn't fit into it.

Comment: You chould simply add: `flex-shrink: 0;` and they wouldn't shrink. You could also combine the use of `display: inline-block` on the *children* and `whitespace: nowrap` on the *parent*. There are many solutions, I just don't understand why you want to float your elements when it's not what float is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be difficult if you want to use float. But fairly easy if you can change your elements to `inline-block` insteed which, based on your question, I think it won't break your layout (and you can keep the size of each column). Then you just have to add `white-space:nowrap` to  the container. Like this:

```css
.container {overflow:auto; white-space:nowrap;}
.container div {
  width:140px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```